# Bulma center columns but make extra columns on bottom stick to left

Tags: html, css, bulma

I want the columns to be in the center of the screen, like the picture below
[image]

But I want the slides on the bottom to align to the left
[image]

```
            <div class="columns is-multiline is-flex-mobile pt-6">

                <div class="black column mt-4 ml-2 mr-4">

                    d
                </div>
                <div class="black column mt-4 ml-2 mr-4">

                    d
                </div>
                <div class="black column mt-4 ml-2 mr-4">

                    d
                </div>
                <div class="black column mt-4 ml-2 mr-4">

                    d
                </div>
                <div class="black column mt-4 ml-2 mr-4">

                    d
                </div>
                <div class="black column mt-4 ml-2 mr-4">

                    d
                </div>
            </div>
```

Right now, the columns are aligning to the center like the first picture, but the bottom one is not being aligned to the left, instead the bottom slide is centered

Comment: show your css code, pls

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov      
 .black {
            background-color: black;
            min-width: 318px;
            max-width: 318px;
        }

The rest is unedited bulma css